# rake db:drop doesn't work with Oracle XE 11G

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, rake

Hi I have found that rake db:drop doesn't work with Oracle. I wanted to rerun some migrations to do some testing from the beginning of my migrations but get this error when I do **rake db:drop**

```
NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24005: Inappropriate utilities used to perform DDL on AQ table SYSTEM.DEF$_AQCALL
: DROP TABLE "DEF$_AQCALL" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
```

The only thing I was able to do to save myself(as I manually deleted a table in the rails console, and the migrations would think that only the last migration hadn't run) was do rake db:schema:load to load the schema.rb.

Comment: Maybe you should specify what oracle platform you're using. On Heroku as well it isn't possible to use `rake db:drop`, you have to use a special command.

Comment: I'm using Oracle XE 11G.

Comment: My next thought is that I could have deleted wherever the migrations are kept track of which I think is in the schema_migrations table in the database.

Comment: yoyodunno maybe you could also write additional migrations which drop the tables and recreate them.